# is there a way to convert a project built in Ant to a Maven project?

Tags: maven, ant

Since Ant is obsolete, and Maven uses the same xml file as Ant, is there a way to convert a project built in Ant to a Maven project?

Comment: First Maven does *NOT* use the same xml file as Ant... and of course you can migrate a project from Ant to Maven...first step is to [follow directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), second identify the dependencies you need add them to a pom file ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do that.

Follow the steps outlined by khmarbaise in the comments.